# Site stats: "1% answered"

Tags: bug, status-completed

For me, the site stats show "1% answered".

I guess that is a bug?

Screenie:

[image: 1% Answered...]

Comment: I'll make sure this gets to a dev.

Comment: Related: [Incorrect Answer Rate being displayed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125117/16487).  Not sure it accounts for my -265%.

Comment: @C.Ross Ross That link is broken, can you fix it (Interested to read the other one)?

Comment: Related: [The percentage of answered questions is wrong](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/475/1452)

Comment: Done. <!--Dirty hack -->

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recently converted some internal v1 [API](http://api.stackexchange.com) usage over to v2.0.  Doing this conversion introduced a bug in the site stats.  It's since been fixed and all should be back to normal.

Answer (score 10):

I see your bug and raise you an order of magnitude.

[image: Negative Answered Percentage]